# Left col top/bottom on mobile with bootstrap 3 and two sidebars

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am trying to use the bootstrap 3 grid system to make one part of the left sidebar display on top, and another at the bottom on mobile. The right sidebar is giving me problems.

The "Left col bottom" is pushed down by the "Right col". When "Right col" is higher, the "Left col bottom" is pushed out of the page, when using `col-md-pull-9`. I understand that using more than 12 cols will push stuff down. Is there a way to avoid it?

http://www.bootply.com/t79A9Q20SW

```
<div class="row">

    <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 side" role="complementary">
      <div style="height:40px;background-color:red;"><p>(Red) Left col top (top mobile)</p></div>
    </aside>

    <section class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div style="height:180px;background-color:green;"><p>(Green) Main content</p></div>
    </section>


    <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 side" role="complementary">
      <div style="height:140px;background-color:silver;">(Grey) Right col (bottom mobile)<br>This pushes the "Left col bottom" down/away</div>   
    </aside>


    <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 side col-md-pull-9" role="complementary">
        <div style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">(Yellow) Left col bottom (bottom mobile)(.col-md-pull-9 woks partially when Right col is not high)</div>
    </aside>

</div>
<div class="row" style="background-color:grey;"><p align="center">Bottom line</p></div>
```

(Without the right sidebar things are much easier http://www.bootply.com/NlsKWaUFq4)

Duplicating stuff and using the Bootstrap visibility classes, will probably solve it. But it is not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to isolate sections like ((first left aside + content + second left aside) + right aside)

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">        
            <aside class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 side" role="complementary">
              <div style="height:40px;background-color:red;"><p>(Red) First left aside block</p></div>
            </aside>
            <section class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 main-content">
                <div style="height:180px;background-color:green;"><p>(Green) Main content</p></div>
            </section>
            <aside class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 side side-2" role="complementary">
                <div style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">(Yellow) Second left aside block</div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>

    <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 side" role="complementary">
      <div style="height:140px;background-color:silver;">(Grey) Right aside</div>   
    </aside>

</div>
<div class="row" style="background-color:grey;"><p align="center">Bottom line</p></div>
```

and css

```
@media (min-width:992px){
    .main-content{float:right!important;}
    .side-2{float:left!important;}
}
```

**Update**: http://www.bootply.com/Ho1wjgKCGx

Comment: Thanks! I added clear:left; to .side-2 in case "First left aside" is higher than "Main content" http://www.bootply.com/RxKh31aH6n

Comment: Adding an extra "Right aside (top mobile)" can be done like this: http://www.bootply.com/1EcufJM6O4